# Why is VS Code not continuing Markdown lists?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

For some reason VS Code has stopped automatically continuing lists, specifically in markdown docs. That is, while editing a list, pressing the enter key doesn't add another `-` or `*` to the next line.

I've been digging through settings and I'm entirely stuck on where to look. The only Markdown extension I have manually installed right now is MarkdownLint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not a feature of the builtin [Markdown extension of VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/markdown-language-features). At least- at the time of this writing, there is no such default behaviour, and looking through the list of settings, I don't see one to enable such behaviour. Indeed, googling "`github vscode issues markdown list continue`", I find https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/117119, where this was raised as a feature-request, but closed for being achievable using extensions, listing [`yzhang.markdown-all-in-one`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzhang.markdown-all-in-one) as an example <sup><sub>(which I have no affiliation with)</sub></sup>.

Perhaps you at one point had the `yzhang.markdown-all-in-one` and then accidentally uninstalled it- in which case you can just install it again.

Comment: +1 This extension does exactly what I needed, but for some reason it changes the styling of strings enclosed in back tick quotes so now my markdown looks different.

Comment: @EricMutta strings enclosed by backticks are rendered as code blocks in markdown. Or do you mean that it changes the styling of the code?